# Custom Tables in PaperTrail with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm pretty new to Rails, and trying to use [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/tree/rails4) to handle versioning for all of my models. I'm using PostgreSQL. I want to store the versions table for each model as a separate table, which the PaperTrail `README` assures me is possible (though it's been marked as an issue several times in the Rails 3 branch).

If I'm subclassing `Version` like so:

```
# Allow PaperTrail versions to be in a separate table.
class FooVersion < Version
  self.table_name = :foo_versions

  # For Postgres, according to PaperTrail README
  self.sequence_name = :foo_version_id_sequence
end
```

Is there a way to get PaperTrail to generate this migration for me? All it seems to want to do is generate a generic migration for a Version table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, looking at the [code](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/tree/master/lib/generators/paper_trail/templates) it does not seem like paper_trail will generate it for you.
There are only two migration file templates. One is for the generic `versions` table, and the other is for adding an `object_changes` column.

If there are no differences between your custom tables and the generic table other than the name, you can copy the generic migration and replace the table name and index accordingly.